# How can we setting sort order in RDLC via C# code? (without report designer)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sorting, rdlc

I'm currently working on a ASP.net MVC project and using RDLC Report to generate excel file.

How can we setting sort order (ASC or DESC) in RDLC via C# code? (without report designer).

I know how to setting sort column dynamically by Report Parameter, but I cannot find how to setting sort order by report parameter.

Can anyone guide me?

Thank you.

Comment: You could sort the datasource before you send it to the reporter.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try this one.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether my answer will help you or not but i will pay it it forward regardless. I have tried a few lines where im using Lambda and assuming it will apply even in your situation.
`var productQuery = (from product in unitOfWork.Repository<Product>().Table  select product).AsQueryable(); If (productName == "Vehicle")  {productQuery = productQuery.Where(a=>a.ProductStatus != "New" && a.ProductNumber !=null).OrderByDescending(a=>a.ProductNumber).AsQueryable();  };`